# Explaining a SELECT statement script in detail for MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

For one of the questions in my computing coursework, I was asked to explain the following SQL script in detail:

```
SELECT exam_board, COUNT(*)
FROM subjects
GROUP BY exam_board;
```

Below is what I have written in response to that question. I was just wondering if I forgot to include something, or if I incorrectly stated something.Any feedback at all would be greatly appreciated!

The script begins with a SELECT statement. A SELECT statement retrieves records from one or more tables or databases (, the data that is returned is then stored inside a result table, which is called a result-set). ‘COUNT (*)’ is a function which returns (all (, as there is an asterisk)) the number of rows which match a specified criteria and it gives a total number of records fetched in a query. Therefore ‘SELECT exam_board, COUNT(*) FROM subjects’ means that the script will return all exam boards from the ‘exam_board’ column in the ‘subjects’ table with their count (of how many subjects are of that exam board). Finally the last line is ‘GROUP BY exam_board;’ the ‘GROUP BY’ clause is often used in SELECT statements to collect data from a number of records. Its purpose is to group the results in one or more columns. In this case it was grouped by ‘exam_board’, meaning that the result of the query will be grouped into a column of the exam boards.

Comment: this is not even a question..

Comment: this is the basic sql.  i think better you reffer https://www.w3schools.com/sql/   it will helps to get more knowledge about sql

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework, not a specific coding problem.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the effect of GROUP BY is to reduce the result set to one row per distinct value in the grouping column (exam_board in this query).

So there might be 10,000 rows in the subjects table, but only four distinct values for exam_board. Using GROUP BY means you will only have four rows in the result set, exactly one row for each exam_board.

Then the COUNT(*) will be the count of rows that were "collapsed" for each respective group.

I request that you do not copy & paste my answer, but write your own answer in your own words. My writing style is pretty different from yours, so if you copy & paste, it'll be obvious to your teacher that you lifted this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this not the best answer.

SELECT can return not only data from the tables, but any result of any function, for example SELECT VERSION() returns a version of server software.

An asterisk as a parameter for COUNT(*) does not matter at all. You can put here any column or function, even COUNT(VERSION()), the result will be the same.

*‘SELECT exam_board, COUNT() FROM subjects’* will return a single row with two columns: the total number of rows in table 'subjects' and the value of 'exam_board' column in the first row of the table.

Content of the table:

```
mysql> select exam_board from subjects;
+------------+
| exam_board |
+------------+
| 2          |
| 2          |
| 3          |
| 3          |
| 3          |
+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Mixing together column values and a function returning a single value like SUM(), MIN(), MAX() etc without grouping functions:

```
mysql> select exam_board, count(*) from subjects;
+------------+----------+
| exam_board | count(*) |
+------------+----------+
| 2          |        5 |
+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And only with grouping operator we will get the desired result: the count of records for each value of exam_board field.

```
mysql> select exam_board, count(*) from subjects group by exam_board;
+------------+----------+
| exam_board | count(*) |
+------------+----------+
| 2          |        2 |
| 3          |        3 |
+------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```